# format a date in the rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a date of birth in the rails model and I display it in different places.  Every time I have to specifically format it in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.  Is there something I can do in my model so that every time I get the dob out it comes in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* define a quick `formatted_birthday` method in your model, but if you're just outputting this to views you can use Rails' built in date formatting output:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      birthday: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Then in your view just use:

```
<%= l person.birthday, :format => 'birthday' %>
```

Or you can change `birthday` to `default` in the format definition and you can omit the `:format` option all together.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. In config/initializers/some_initializer.rb

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Now all your dates will always be out in the above format.
If you want to selectively choose it only sometimes. Then

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:myformat] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

And then you can use whereever you like

```
your_date.to_s(:myformat)
```